# Slow tests on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rspec, capybara

I can understand this question is quite general, but I'm having an issue that my tests on Heroku are incredibly slow (20+ minutes) vs when I run them locally that takes around 9 or 10 minutes. And I was wondering if I could get pointed in a good direction on what the issue might be. This is my `rails_helper.rb`:

```
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

# Prevent database truncation if the environment is production
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?

require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'shoulda/matchers'

require 'sidekiq/testing'
Sidekiq::Testing.fake!

require 'public_activity/testing'
PublicActivity.enabled = false

# Checks for pending migrations before tests are run.
ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

require 'capybara/rspec'


Capybara.asset_host = ENV['CAPYBARA_ASSET_HOST'] || "http://localhost:#{ENV.fetch('PORT', 3000)}"
Capybara.register_driver :headless_chrome do |app|
  chrome_bin = ENV.fetch('GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM', nil)
  chrome_opts = chrome_bin ? { 'binary': chrome_bin } : {}
  capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome chromeOptions: { args: %w[headless disable-gpu disable-dev-shm-usage no-sandbox] }.merge(chrome_opts)
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new app, browser: :chrome, desired_capabilities: capabilities
end
Capybara.javascript_driver = :headless_chrome
Capybara.server = :puma, { Silent: true }

# NOTE: Running with sauce REQUIRES SAUCE CONNECT tunnel driver
# so that saucelabs instance can communicate with your test server.
# run with...
# bin/sc -u obiefernandez -k 24e2ec72-ff16-4526-9a35-d7e8bd180d5a
#
# require "selenium/webdriver"
# Capybara.register_driver :sauce do |app|
#   caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome()
#   caps['platform'] = 'macOS 10.12'
#   caps['version'] = '52.0'
#   sauce_endpoint = "http://obiefernandez:24e2ec72-ff16-4526-9a35-d7e8bd180d5a@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub"
#   Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new app, :browser => :remote, :url => sauce_endpoint, :desired_capabilities => caps
# end
# Capybara.javascript_driver = :sauce

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods

  config.before(:suite) do
    # compile front-end and load manifest
    `bin/webpack`
    Webpacker::Manifest.load
    DatabaseCleaner.allow_remote_database_url = true
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation, { pre_count: true, except: %w(ar_internal_metadata) }
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

  config.around(:each) do |example|
    DatabaseCleaner.cleaning do
      example.run
    end
  end

  config.backtrace_exclusion_patterns << %r{/rails_helper\.rb:}

  module SignInHelpers
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    class_methods do
      def managing_project(&block)
        if block_given?
          let!(:project, &block)
          let(:organization) { project.organization }
          let(:project_manager) { create(:user, organization: organization, organization_admin: true) }
        else
          let!(:organization) { create(:organization_with_project_manager) }
          let!(:project) { create(:project, organization: organization) }
          let(:project_manager) { organization.admins.first }
        end

        before do
          set_current_user(project_manager)
          sign_in(project_manager) if respond_to?(:sign_in)
        end
      end
    end
  end

  config.fixture_path = 'spec/fixtures'

  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller
  Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers.module_eval do
    alias_method :original_sign_in, :sign_in
    def sign_in(resource, deprecated = nil, scope: nil)
      original_sign_in(resource, scope: scope)
      # needed because devise integration helper bypasses normal ApplicationController logic
      set_current_user(resource)
    end
  end

  config.include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers, type: :feature
  Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers.module_eval do
    alias_method :original_sign_in, :sign_in
    def sign_in(resource, scope: nil)
      original_sign_in(resource, scope: scope)
      # needed because devise integration helper bypasses normal ApplicationController logic
      set_current_user(resource)
    end
  end

  config.include SignInHelpers # needed everywhere

  # https://github.com/state-machines/state_machines-rspec
  config.include StateMachinesRspec::Matchers

  module IntegrationHelpers
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    included do
      subject { page }
    end

    def visit(url, *args)
      super(polymorphic_path(url), *args)
    rescue
      super
    end
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    Sidekiq::Worker.clear_all
  end

  config.include IntegrationHelpers, type: :feature
end

Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
  config.integrate do |with|
    with.test_framework :rspec
    with.library :rails
  end
end
```

Comment: Set RSpecs `profile_examples` to around 25 - https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/configuration/profile-examples#setting-%60profile-examples%60-to-2-shows-2-examples - then run the tests on heroku and locally - if the slowest 25 tests Rspec reports are basically the same but the times of each are appeoximately double then it's most likely just the resource difference between Heroku dynos (cpu, memory, etc) and your local machine

Comment: @ThomasWalpole thank you, will try this out.

Comment: Oddly enough when running in the heroku ci debugger the tests ran in normal time.